# Copying array of NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, copy, nsnumber

I'm quite new in Objective-c leaning so if my question is too stupid, please don't kill me ^^

There's my problem :

***Architecture : ***

I have an objet : *Guest* with a property : *listOfPricePaidByGuest*
This property is an array of NSNumber.
All the guest are in this NSMutableArray : *currentListOfBeneficiaries*

***Situation : ***

I have a UIViewController where i allow the user to modify the values in *listOfPricePaidByGuest*

I want to allow the user to cancel all the modification.
So when the view is loaded, i'm copying the guest in a new mutableArray : *tempListOfBeneficiaries* (i've already implemented the *NSMutableCoying* delegate and checked that the two objects have a different memory adress).

When the user click on *Save*, i'm juste removing the view, beacause all the modification are done.

When the user click on *Cancel*, i'm juste using setArray method to the original listOfPricePaidByGuest.

The fact is that all NSnumber in my tempArray are also modificated and i don't understand why...
I've tried everything i could...

***Question : ***

Does anyone know a method to get these values unchanged ?

***Some code : ***

**Copying to tempArray**

```
    for (Guest *newGuest in self.currentGrocery.listOfBeneficiaries)
    {
        // Copying original guest
        Guest *copyGuest = [newGuest mutableCopy];

        for (NSNumber *aNumber in newGuest.listOfPricePaidByGuest)
        {
            int index = [newGuest.listOfPricePaidByGuest indexOfObject:aNumber];

            // Copying NSNumber in newGuest.listOfPricePaidByGuest
            NSNumber *newNumber = [aNumber copy];

            // Replace current object
            [copyGuest.listOfPricePaidByGuest replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newNumber];

            // Releasing current copied number
            [newNumber release];
        }

        // Add it to tempArray
        [self.tempListOfBeneficiaries addObject:copyGuest];

        // Releasing current copiedGuest
        [copyGuest release];
    }
```

*** Implementation for NSMutableCopying delegate ***

```
    -(id)mutableCopyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
    {
        Guest *guestCopy = [[Guest allocWithZone: zone] init];
        [guestCopy setListOfGrocery:self.listOfGrocery];
        [guestCopy setListOfPricePaidByGuest:self.listOfPricePaidByGuest];

        [guestCopy setGuestName:self.guestName];
        [guestCopy setGuestEmail:self.guestEmail];
        [guestCopy setGuestNickname:self.guestNickname];
        [guestCopy setGuestPhone:self.guestPhone];

        [guestCopy setTotalGuestDepense:self.totalGuestDepense];
        [guestCopy setTotalGuestDepenseToPayAfterReeq:self.totalGuestDepenseToPayAfterReeq];

        [guestCopy setIsComming:self.isComming];
        [guestCopy setIsSend:self.isSend];

        return guestCopy;
    }
```

PS : Sorry for the english... It's quite late and... Well i'm french so it explains everything :P

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Tu parle l'anglais mieux que je parle la français.  For clarification though, you want to be able to set one NSArray equal to another?

Comment: You need to construct a new array, not just replace individual array elements.  This should happen within `[Guest mutableCopy]`.  Can you post your current `[Guest mutableCopy]` source?  Also, if you want save / cancel behavior, make the changes to `tempArrayOfBeneficiaries`.  On save, copy the changes into `currentListOfBeneficiaries`.  On cancel, discard it.

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks ^^ I juste to replace my old values to my currentArray.

Comment: @Dondragmer I've alredy tried to do this... But it was more complicated... I had some problem when saving the Guests with the NSUserdefaults...
I'm addind my mutableCopySource right now :)!

Comment: @Dondragmer The problem is not when i'm doing trying to replace my array by the old one, i have an NSLog that show my two array content all the time, and when a modification on theses NSNumber is done,my two arrays of NSNumbers are affected!

Comment: NSNumber is a non-mutable object.  If you do `[myArray copy]` or `[myArray mutableCopy]` on the original array you will automatically have a copy of all the values.  Once that is done, modifying one array will have no effect on the other one.  If you want to modify one array but then be able to "restore" it from the other, simply store the address of the "backup" array into the pointer to the changed array (though remembering to `release` the changed array, if not ARC).  Or you can make a copy of the "backup" array and store that in place of the changed array.

Comment: It should be noted that your `mutableCopyWithZone` method is not making a copy of the `listOfPricePaidByGuest` array (nor is it making a copy of any other object).  If you want these to be copied so that modifying the original Guest object will not modify the copy, you must make copies of the individual objects in the Guest object, not simply copy their pointers.

Comment: By the way, you're not really doing anything especially different from what you would do with C structs.  There's no magic to Objective-C -- it's just structures.  With a C struct you'd understand that simply copying the struct would not copy the values pointed to from the struct.  Same thing with Objective-C.

Comment: @HotLicks you mean thant implementing my mutableCopyWithZone method like this, is the right way ?
`NSMutableArray *myNewArrayOfNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSNumber *aNumber in self.listOfPricePaidByGuest)
{
    NSNumber *newNumber = [aNumber copy];
    [myNewArrayOfNumber addObject:newNumber];
    [newNumber release];
}
[guestCopy setListOfPricePaidByGuest:myNewArrayOfNumber];
[myNewArrayOfNumber release];`

Comment: You don't need to create new NSNumbers, so no need for the loop.  Just use the `copy` or `mutableCopy` method of NSArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the array, not the NSNumbers.  At the moment, you always have one array, never two.  In `[Guest mutableCopyWithZone:]`, you must copy the listOfGrocery and listOfPricePaidByGuest arrays:

```
[guestCopy setListOfGrocery:[self.listOfGrocery mutableCopy]];
[guestCopy setListOfPricePaidByGuest:[self.listOfPricePaidByGuest mutableCopy]];
```

It might be better still to have `setListOfGrocery` and `setListOfPricePaidByGuest` carry out this copying step, unless there are times when you'll need to retain the input array.  If you're defining these with `@property`, just use replace `assign` or `retain` with `copy`.

Also, is this using Automatic Reference Counting or Garbage Collection?  If not, the copies need to be released at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much !! It finally work! I didn't knew this, I have to check all my Array! Thanks to you i might have some other bugs corrected too :)